# How to solve this JSON error

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am new in JSON, I am not sure how to stringify the data .

Below I wrote a code for alert the content of the JSON but some error are shown, how do I solve these errors?

```js
 $('.savebutton').on('click', function (){

        var myjson = {}
        
        var  mainobject =[]
        myjson.push(mainobject);
        mainobject.main = {}
        mainobject.main.tittle = "'hai'";
        mainobject.main.sub = [];
        var subobejct = {}
        mainobject.main.sub.push(subobejct);
        subobejct.tittle = "levler";
        subobejct.tasks = []
        var task = {};
        subobejct.tasks.push(task);

        alert(JSON.stringify(myjson));
        return myjson;
   });
```

Comment: What error is shown? What is "some error"?

Comment: "FunctionView.js:542 Uncaught TypeError: myjson.push is not a function" i dontknow how it solve

Comment: What is the target JSON structure that you are aiming for? You cannot call "push" method of an Object, it is a method of an Array.

Comment: Learn some language fundamentals. You won't get far if you are not even familiar with the most common APIs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here you have take `var myjson = {}` as object you can not use `push()` on object it is for array variable only.